# Открытие новых окон через qlistwidget pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

У меня есть код, в котором открывается `qlistwidget` при нажатии на кнопку.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии `Item 1` в `qlistwidget` открывалось второе окно с надписью `1`, так же с `Item 2` в `qlistwidge`t должно открываться  второе окно с надписью `2`.

main1.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui  
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)                    
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.565, y1:0, x2:0.508475, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 103, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnPullOut = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)    
        self.btnPullOut.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 31, 23))
        self.btnPullOut.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#btnPullOut{\n"
"      background:white;\n"
"      border:0px;\n"
"      }")
        self.btnPullOut.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("33333.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btnPullOut.setIcon(icon)
        self.btnPullOut.setObjectName("btnPullOut")
        self.frame1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 480))
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background:black;")
        self.frame1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame1.setObjectName("frame1")
        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 0, 480))
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet("background:white;")
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame2.setObjectName("frame2")
        self.btnPullOut.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))



class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def itClicked(self, item):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            None, 
            "ListWidget", 
            "Вы нажали: {}".format(item.text())
        )


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)   
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)      

        self.btnPullOut.setCheckable(True) 
        self.btnPullOut.click()
        self.btnPullOut.installEventFilter(self)

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()     
        self.listWidget.addItems(["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", ])
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.listWidget.itClicked)
        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setFont (QFont ("Arial", 22)); 
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item:hover {background: rgba(158, 158, 158, 40);}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {background: transparent;}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {color: black;}\n"
"")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        lay.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 20, 0, 0)

        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame2, b'size', self)
        self._animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QSize(0, self.height()))
        self._animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(121, self.height()))
        self._animation.setDuration(200)

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if self.btnPullOut is watched:
            if event.type() == 2 and self.btnPullOut.isChecked(): 
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
                self._animation.start()
            if event.type() == 2 and (not self.btnPullOut.isChecked()):
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
                self._animation.start()
        return super(MainWindow,self).eventFilter(watched, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = MainWindow()  
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui  
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)                    
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.565, y1:0, x2:0.508475, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 103, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnPullOut = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)    
        self.btnPullOut.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 31, 23))
        self.btnPullOut.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#btnPullOut{\n"
"      background:white;\n"
"      border:0px;\n"
"      }")
        self.btnPullOut.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("33333.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btnPullOut.setIcon(icon)
        self.btnPullOut.setObjectName("btnPullOut")
        self.frame1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 480))
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background:black;")
        self.frame1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame1.setObjectName("frame1")
        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 0, 480))
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet("background:white;")
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame2.setObjectName("frame2")
        self.btnPullOut.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


'''
class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def itClicked(self, item):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            None, 
            "ListWidget", 
            "Вы нажали: {}".format(item.text())
        )
'''

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)   
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)      

        self.btnPullOut.setCheckable(True) 
        self.btnPullOut.click()
        self.btnPullOut.installEventFilter(self)

#        self.listWidget = ListWidget() 
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()                                # +++
        self.listWidget.addItems(["Item 0", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", ])

#        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.listWidget.itClicked)
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.openWindow)                    # +++

        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setFont (QFont ("Arial", 22)); 
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item:hover {background: rgba(158, 158, 158, 40);}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {background: transparent;}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {color: black;}\n"
"")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        lay.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 20, 0, 0)

        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame2, b'size', self)
        self._animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QSize(0, self.height()))
        self._animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(121, self.height()))
        self._animation.setDuration(200)

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if self.btnPullOut is watched:
            if event.type() == 2 and self.btnPullOut.isChecked(): 
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
                self._animation.start()
            if event.type() == 2 and (not self.btnPullOut.isChecked()):
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
                self._animation.start()
        return super(MainWindow,self).eventFilter(watched, event)

    def openWindow(self, item):                                  # +++
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        row = self.listWidget.row(item)
        self.widget.setWindowTitle(f'{row}')
        self.widget.resize(300, 200)
        self.widget.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = MainWindow()  
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]